# query mysql in php to get the difference between two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with the same structure to get users finger print data and i want to get from the first table data that is not exist in the second table and insert it into the second table 
the structure of two tables:

- ID
- USER_ID
- check_time
- check_type
- sensor_id

Comment: What decides if the data is not already in table 2 ? Just user_id or something else.

Comment: i want to get the data found in table 1 and not exist in table 2 and insert it in table 2 @HonzaHaering

Comment: user_id and check_time @AbhikChakraborty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `insert into select from` using some additional join as

```
insert into table2 
select 
t1.* from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.check_time = t2.check_time
where t2.user_id is null and t2.check_time is null
```

Comment: t1.user_id = t2.user_id or t1.user_id != t2.user_id

Comment: `t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.check_time = t2.check_time`

Comment: I think Join should be outer

Comment: what this error : Error in Processing Request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: That could be some PHP fatal error. check your apache error log

Comment: but i run query in phpmyadmin not in php code and it run correctly on test database but on live database it take long time and get this error @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Looks like you are missing indexes on the tables use `explain select 
t1.* from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id and t1.check_time = t2.check_time
where t2.user_id is null and t2.check_time is null` and share the result.

Comment: how can i share the result data @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Edit your question and copy paste what you see after running the above query `explain select ...`

Comment: id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
1 SIMPLE t1 ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 32234 
1 SIMPLE t2 ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 438506 Using where; Not exists

Comment: can this view help u ? @AbhikChakraborty

Comment: Yes add the following indexes... `alter table table1 user_time(user_id,check_time)` and `alter table table2 user_time(user_id,check_time)` make sure to take a backup of the tables before applying indexes. This will resolve the issue.